# Interactive plots in Jupyter

Tags: python, visualization, jupyter, ipython

I'm looking for Jupyter extension to plot interactive graphs. For example I need to plot twenty time series lines with order to examine data. Only plugin which I've found is bqplot https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot but its documentation is too complicated.

Could you advice some other free tool or help with bqplot?

I can't plot lines with different colors.

```
unitIds = commonSeries['UnitId'].unique()
commonSeries = commonSeries.sort_values(by=['Date','UnitId'], ascending=True)
commonSeries = commonSeries.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(commonSeries['Date']))

plt.clear()
x_ord = OrdinalScale()
y_sc = LinearScale()
lines = []

for unitId in unitIds:    
    timeseries = commonSeries.loc[commonSeries['UnitId'] == unitId]
    line = plt.Lines(x=timeseries.index, y=timeseries['Value'], scales={'x': x_ord, 'y': y_sc}, colors=['red','green','blue'])
    lines.append(line)

plt.Figure(marks=lines)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[Plotly](https://plot.ly/) is by far the best interactive visualization library/platform I have used, and it works very well with IPython/Jupyter too.

There are [tutorials](https://plot.ly/python/offline/#generating-offline-graphs-within-jupyter-notebook) on Plotly's docs which help you integrate it with Jupyter. [Another tutorial](https://plot.ly/python/ipython-notebook-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1):

I've found simple, useful and opensource plugin: http://holoviews.org

Answer (score 1):

[Bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) and [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) both feature interactive visualizations and can be used in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `%matplotlib notebook` the same way you would use `%matplotlib inline`.

https://www.reddit.com/r/IPython/comments/36p360/try_matplotlib_notebook_for_interactive_plots/